# how to build an linear regression model for daily predictions

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

i need to create a prediction model that predicts the quantity of an item per day...

this how my data look like on DB...

```
item id |date         | quantity

1000    |2020-02-03   | 5
```

what I did is converted the date to :

- year number
- number of the week in year
- weekday number

I trained this model on a dataset of 100,000 items with RegressionFastForest, RegressionFastTree, LbfgsPoissonRegression, FastTreeTweedie

but results are not so good (**RMSE SCORE OF 3.5 - 4**)

am I doing this wrong ?

I am using ML.NET if its matter

thanks

Comment: Try using time series forecast (sample - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/time-series-demand-forecasting) and not use the "item id" column. Alternatively, you can try to run the data inside Model Builder to see how that works (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/automate-training-with-model-builder)

Comment: but predication should be by itemId for a specific future date

Comment: Ok, so item ID is categorical. I thought it was just a primary key from a database. Still give Model Builder a try. It should be able to handle dates.

Comment: unfortunately  the builder wont with forecasting scenarios for now...

series forecast is the only way to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

There're several techniques of time series forecasting. But the main point: we don't seek dependency of `value` on `date`. Instead, we're seeking dependence of `value[i]` on `value[i-1]`.

Most common techniques are family of **ARIMA** models and recurrent neural networks. I would recommend to read about them. But, if you don't have much time or something else, there's something that can help. And it's *Auto ARIMA* models.

Implementation of auto ARIMA exists at least in Python and R. Here's python version:

```py
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima

model = auto_arima(y)
```

where `y` is your time series.

**P.S.** Even though it is called *auto* model (which means that the algorithm will choose best hyperparameters by itself), you should still understand what does: **p, q, P, Q** and **S** mean.

Comment: if u understand u:

u mean i need to add to the model what was the previous quantity of the item to create a connection between each point ?

Comment: Well, if you want to use _ARIMA_ - no. The `y` value in my example is a simple 1D array of time series values

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with directly applying linear regression to your data.

1) If `item id` is an index of sorts and does not reflect physical properties of the item, then it is a categorical feature. Use [OneHotEncoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to replace it with regression-friendly labels.

2) If you assume that you data may have a cyclical dependence on the time of the day/week/month, use `sin` and `cos` of those functions. It will not work with year, as it is not periodic. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/avanwyk/encoding-cyclical-features-for-deep-learning) is a good guide with examples in Python.

Good luck!

P. S. I usually use LogisticRegression in tasks with sparse representations of categorical features (OneHotEncoding) for benchmark. It will not be as good as a state-of-the art NN solution, but gives me a clue what the benchmark looks like.